# DataGridView CellLeave not firing

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem that datagridview_CellLeave event is not firing, I searched the net about the problem but I didn't find anything about it, could you please help in this? Following is my code.

```
        /**
     * dataGridView1_CellLeave() method
     * Find sum and populate third cell. 
     */
    private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Cell Leave entry");

        int sum = 0;

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) //if second cell
        {
            sum = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value) *
                  Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);

            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = sum;
            MessageBox.Show("Cell Leave sum: " + sum);
        }
    } //dataGridView1_CellLeave
```

Comment: Do you hook that event up anywhere?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Sorry I am new on C# and VisualStudio, what is the meaning of hooking up event? do you mean a place to trigger it or something?

Comment: Windows events are basically a publish/subscribe scenario... you have created some code that you want executed when the user leaves the cell, now you need to subscribe to the CellLeave event of your dataGridvView1 control. Somewhere in your code you should have a line that reads dataGridView1.CellLeave += dataGridView1_CellLeave  (unless you're using xaml and routed events).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was helpful ... :)

Comment: Cheers mate, good luck. pluralsight.com is a pretty good site for .NET training.   :)

Comment: @Levesque I am stuck in another problem, that the DataGridComboBoxColumn is not updated directly with the new added value, Please check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787389/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-not-updating