# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn not updating

Tags: c#, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have ProcurementFrm that list the available items in a

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
```

using this method:

```
  /**
       Populate combo box in datagrid in procurement screen
      */
    public void populateGridComboBox()
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand sc = new MySqlCommand("select id, ar_desc from minierp_db.items", con);
        //MySqlDataReader reader;
        MySqlDataReader itemReader = null;

        try
        {
            itemReader = sc.ExecuteReader();

            itemDT = new DataTable();

            itemDT.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            itemDT.Columns.Add("ar_desc", typeof(string));
            itemDT.Load(itemReader);

            itemIDcmbColmn.ValueMember = "id";
            itemIDcmbColmn.DisplayMember = "ar_desc";
            itemIDcmbColmn.DataSource = itemDT;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception - populateGridComboBox(): " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            itemReader.Dispose();
        }
    } //populateGridComboBox
```

and  in the same form I have a button that call another form addItemFrm, which enables user from adding a new item. The item is added correctely but it's not reflected directely in the ComboBoxColumn until I close and reopen the ProcurementFrm.

Here how I add the new Item to ComboBoxColumn

```
  public void populateNewAddedItems()
    {
        procurmentsFrm prcFrm = (procurmentsFrm)Application.OpenForms["procurmentsFrm"];
        MySqlConnection connn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=admin");
        MySqlCommand sc = new MySqlCommand("select id, ar_desc from minierp_db.items", connn);


        //itemDT = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn itemCmbClmn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();


            itemCmbClmn.ValueMember = itemID.ToString();
            itemCmbClmn.DisplayMember = txtItemAr.Text;

            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            DataTable itemDataTable = prcFrm.ItemData;
            bs.DataSource = itemDataTable;
            itemCmbClmn.DataSource = bs;
```

Any Help Please? I want the comboBox to get updated directely.

Comment: Do BindingSources require a DataBind() after you set the DataSource?

Comment: I tried to re-call the populateGridComboBox() method after insert, but still the same problem, the new added item, would not appear until I close and re-open the form.

Comment: @jotnarta I have not done much work with DataGrids so this may just be a lack of understanding but in your populateNewAddedItems method you are creating a new ComboBoxColumn instead of referencing itemIDcmbColmn as populateGridComboBox does. Shouldn't you be referencing itemIDcmbColmn? I assume that is the column defined on your datagrid.